# Intellisense in VSCode and Python type hinting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, type-hinting

I have a question about intellisense in VSCode and type hinting in Python that I do not understand.

If I add type hinting, I sometimes get completions and sometimes I do not and I don't fully understand why.

For example. If I do, in a plain .py file, the following minimal reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig: plt.Figure = plt.figure(10, clear=True)
ax: plt.Axes = plt.subplot()
```

I get completion as I expect for `ax` but not for `fig`, i.e., if I write `ax.` I get a popup with the available methods but not the same for `fig.` As far as I can tell, the types seems correct. How can I understand this behavior?

Comment: Is this a Jupyter notebook or plain .py?

Comment: It is a plain .py file (revised my question to include this information).

Comment: This would merit a [mcve]. Maybe you'd also be able to make sense of it yourself then. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I'm not sure what was missing or how my question was ill-posed. I have tried to clarify further. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: With your example, if I start typing `fig.` on a new line, I get the expected autocompletion suggestions, starting with `add_artist`, `add_axes`, etc. It's hard to know what's different between your environment and mine. The basics: is VSCode configured to use the right Python environment where `matplotlib` is installed? (I expect yes if `ax.` gives you completion, but I still have to ask.)

Comment: Note that I still get the autocompletion even if I remove the type hints you added, because Intellisense is getting the return types from the functions called to initialize those variables.

Comment: I'm testing all this with Python 3.11.5 and `matplotlib==3.8.3`, maybe share the versions you're using, and your OS, in case that makes a difference.